# python dynamically answer yes/no to terminal prompt

Tags: python, bash, shell, automation, command-prompt

#### prompt question generator

```
class SynthesisPromptGenerator:
    def wait_key(self):
        ''' Wait for a key press on the console and return it. '''
        result = None

        for singlePrompt in ["questionCat", "questionDog"]:
            try:
                result = raw_input(singlePrompt)
                print 'input is: ', result
            except IOError:
                pass

        return result
```

I have a PromptGenerator that will generate multiple terminal prompt questions, and after answering first question, then second will pop up, as

```
questionCat
(and wait for keyboard input)

questionDog
(and wait for keyboard input)
```

#### my goal is to automatically and dynamically answer to the questions

```
class PromptResponder:
    def respond(self):
        generator = SynthesisPromptGenerator()
        child = pexpect.spawn(generator.wait_key())

        child.expect("\*Cat\*")
        child.sendline("yes")
        child.expect("\*Dog\*")
        child.sendline("no")
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    responder = PromptResponder()
    responder.respond()
```

- if the prompt question contains `Cat` then answer `yes`
- if the prompt question contains `Dog` then answer `no`

So it comes to:

1. how to get the prompt string from terminal and filter based on it?
2. how to answer multiple prompt questions in python?

I did some search but found most questions are for shell script `echo yes | ./script`, not much doing it `in python`

thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean by "get the prompt string from terminal"? You already _have_ the prompt string, since you passed it as the arg to `raw_input`.

Comment: I'm confused, who is calling what, where, and what is being printed by whom?

Comment: The original version of this question had some code. Why did you remove it?

Comment: [expect command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) will help you.

Comment: @PM2Ring sorry. I'm calling another script (say, x.sh) with many prompt questions to answer. So I want to use a python script to automatically answer to the prompt questions from the sh script. sorry didn't explain myself very well

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'll refactor the question to be more specific. sorry

Comment: Ok. So to make this question a [mcve] you will need to provide a short `x.sh` as well as your attempt at a Python script that tries to interact with `x.sh`. Are you familiar with the `subprocess` module?

Comment: @gzh thanks, do you know how to do it in python? expect seems waiting for the whole question, but here I want to filter the prompt string

Comment: @PM2Ring `subprocess` module seems to be statically answering `yes` or `no` to all prompts, here I'm trying to answer based on the prompt question itself. Not very familiar with `subprocess`, so maybe I missed something. thanks a lot

Comment: There are 2 programs? A parent program that runs a child program and waits for prompts, plus the child program that does the PromptGenerator thing? Is this on Windows / linux or ios?

Comment: @keypoint, there is a python module named [pexpect](http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html)

Comment: @tdelaney yes, two separate programs. one is calling the other

Comment: @gzh fancy, checking that. thanks!

Comment: And which operating system do you use? This is hard to solve on Windows, but on linux / ios you can use `pexpect`.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm on linux, checking pexpect. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use `pexpect`.

See [pexpect on github](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect), [the official docs](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [this handy python for beginners walkthrough on pexpect](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-pexpect-module-in-python).

For an example. Let's say this is your `x.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Continue? [Y/N]: "
read answer
if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ]; then
        echo -n "continuing.."
else
        echo -n "exiting.."
fi
```

You can do this:

```
import os, sys
import pexpect

# It's probably cleaner to use an absolute path here
# I just didn't want to include my directories..
# This will run x.sh from your current directory.
child = pexpect.spawn(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'x.sh'))
child.logfile = sys.stdout
# Note I have to escape characters here because
# expect processes regular expressions.
child.expect("Continue\? \[Y/N\]: ")
child.sendline("Y")
child.expect("continuing..")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
print(child.before)
```

Result of the python script:

```
Continue? [Y/N]: Y
Y
continuing..
```

Although I have to say that it's a bit unusal to use pexpect with a bash script if you have the ability to edit it. It would be simpler to edit the script so that it no longer prompts:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Continue? [Y/N]: "
answer=y
if [ "$answer" != "${answer#[Yy]}" ]; then
        echo "continuing.."
else
        echo "exiting.."
fi
```

Then you're free to just use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to execute it.

```
import os
import subprocess

subprocess.call(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"x.sh"))
```

Or if you want the output as a variable:

```
import os
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"x.sh"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, error = p.communicate()

print(out)
```

I realise this might not be possible for you but it's worth noting.

Comment: No worries, I've added an alternative approach that might be worth a thought.